# Can LogParser output to Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database, logparser

Azure SQL tables require a clustered index and will not accept insertions if one is not present. If one is present LogParser is complaining about a mismatch on the number of columns in the select list vs. the target table.

Is there any way to square this circle? Perhaps embed an expression in LP's select list like '"SELECT DateTime,Thread,Level,Logger,Message,Exception,(select max(id)+1 from loggerTbl)...

It's becoming amazingly difficult to parse plain old azure logs into sql where god intends them to be.

Comment: Is the ID column an identity column? LogParser should ignore identity columns and let the DB create a default (identity) value for them.

Comment: I sure would have thought that was the expected behavior. I'd defined the id column as a seeded/auto-incrementing column but didn't get the desired results. I wouldn't be at all surprised that I'm missed a step either in config or testing that led me to a false negative because this sure seems like how LP would approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure SQL tables require a clustered index and will not accept insertions if one is not present.

That is no longer true. [Azure SQL DB v12](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-v12-whats-new/) no longer has this restrictions. Move your DB to one of the new tiers (Basic, Standard) and your DB will be upgraded to v12.